# unserialize gives false

Tags: php, serialization, curl

been on this for weeks !!!
can't unserialize this file :
[file](http://www.4shared.com/office/SgSrUm0Y/unserialize_test.html)

used `serialize` then `base64_encode` , then transferred the data through a curl call . 
when receiving used `base64_decode` , then

```
$out = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", base64_decode($_POST["data"]) );
```

then `$x=unserialize($out)`

no output , no errors visible in the error log !!!

the file is the output data of the above `preg_replace` 
Thank you

Comment: Why are you messing with the serialized output? If you're going to serialize something and then unserialize it later, don't do arbitrary things to the output.

Comment: you have to do a base64 encoding before sending the data in a post curl request , otherwise problems might occur !

Comment: I'm not talking about base64 encoding the output - that's fine. I'm talking about your `preg_replace()`. What are you trying to replace? Why is that necessary?

Comment: sometimes when you send UTF the lengths of the strings are wrong , so this one fixes them

Comment: @RonanDejhero Are you sure the lengths are wrong? Seems a little unlikely to me. Please can you post the file to somewhere that doesn't require a login to access it? E.g. [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com/). Also `eval()` (and hence the `e` modifier) is evil, use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) instead.

Comment: @DaveRandom http://pastebin.com/ga4xTpu2

Comment: OK that is a bit odd - I'm thinking that you should be base64 encoding the strings before you `serialize()` the data, rather than base64 encoding the serialized string. I'm pretty certain this would solve the problem. But it is weird - the string length is wrong by 10 characters, which is obviously a bug in `serialize()`, but it is not that which it seems to be complaining about, because when I try and unserialize the data the position it complains about is way before the end of the string. Very odd.

Comment: i can't base64 before serializing because the operation goes around objects,arrays and strings , and it works , but not for this set of data ! that's strange , the data that is being serialized have the '~' string , but how does this break the serialization ?